# Can I add to voice actions for smart plug so I can do "Turn plug off in 10 mins"

Tags: voice, google-home, google-assist-api

I have a smart plug connected to a water heater, which is configured in android app "Smart Life" and this is connected to Google Home and I only seem to be able to use voice commands:

- Turn Water On/Off
- Is Water on

So none of the following work:

1. Turn water on/off in 10 mins
2. Turn water on/off at 5pm
3. Turn water on for 10 mins (i.e turn water on, and then turn off in 10 mins)

On Google mini nest it says "sorry, I can't do that at the moment", on some phones it looks up query on the web and on some phones it will set a reminder.
Since on one phone it can set a reminder, so understands "in 10 mins", "for 10 mins" and "at 5pm", and it understands "Turn water on/off", I don't quite understand why it can't do understand my command.
Is there anyway I get get Google to do this by configuring something or writing some code somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You can [create a custom routine in your Assistant settings](https://support.google.com/googlenest/answer/7029585) to turn on or off the water at a scheduled time.

Otherwise, you could use the schedule feature in the Smart Life app itself.